# expect script doesn't work on ssh session

Tags: ssh, expect, totp

I login our company server by ssh, but the server ask my password and otp token.
Since i know my otp secret, so i can generate my otp in my script.

the prompt looks like this:

```
$ ssh mike@relay.office.com
Your password: 
Your token:
```

let's assume my password is "123", and token is "456"
I wrote a expect script like this, which is supposed to work

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh mike@relay.office.com
expect "password:"
send "123\n"
send "456\n"
interact
```

However the prompt just like this:

```
$ ./expect.sh
Your [EMAIL] password: 
Your [VPN] token: 
^[[?65;1;9cInvalid credentials
```

You see, the ssh server return some massy code followed by "Invalid credentials"
I don't understand where the messy code came from.
In normal situation. Even i type the wrong password or token, it will just prompt "Invalid credentials" without any messy code. Is it some sort of `anti-script login` method from our ssh server?

**Some Supplyment**

Per answer below, i need to clarify, i forget to paste `expect` line in my script before. But even with it, the problem stands still.

And another thing i didn't mention before, but maybe related. when i type `ssh mike@xxx.com`. the server returned a QR code.(yeah, QR code in terminal.) it contains `color escape` as well as `some unicode characters`. I'm not sure if `expect` has any bug on handling unicode characters

Answer (score 0):

The "messy code" is a terminal escape sequence, probably intended to change the colour or font of the following error message.

But the main problem here is that as written, your script will launch the ssh command and then *immediately* send the following lines, without waiting for ssh to connect to the remote machine.  You should use `expect` commands to wait for each prompt before sending the response, e.g.

```
spawn ssh mike@relay.office.com
expect "password:"
send "123\n"
expect "token:"
send "456\n"
interact
```

Comment: well, i forget to paste the `expect` line. but the problem stands still

Comment: On the question, you only have expect password. Check here because there's another expect for token, and that's the key. I can tell you expect works OK with SSH.